# Let x and y be positive numbers. Which of the following implies $x^y >= y^x.$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Let x and y be positive numbers. Which of the following implies $x^y \geq y^x$.
$(a)x\leq e\leq y$ $(b) y\leq e\leq x$ $(c) x\leq y\leq e$ or $e\leq y\leq x$ $(d) y\leq x\leq e$ or $e\leq x\leq y$.

I've proceeded with taking log on both sides but is kinda stuck over there, help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$x^y \geq y^x \Longleftrightarrow y \ln(x) \geq x \ln(y) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \geq \frac{\ln(y)}{y}$$

Now study the function
$$t \mapsto \frac{\ln(t)}{t}$$

Comment: Can you post the full solution?